# Selecting distinct values from a join of two large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, distinct

I have an `animals` table with about 3 million records. The table has, among a few other columns, an `id`, `name`, and `owner_id` column. I have an `animal_breeds` table with about 2.5 million records. The table only has an `animal_id` and `breed` column.

I'm trying to find the distinct `breed` values that are associated with a specific `owner_id`, but the query is taking 20 seconds or so. Here's the query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `breed`
FROM `animal_breeds` 
INNER JOIN `animals` ON `animals`.`id` = `animal_breeds`.`animal_id` 
WHERE `animals`.`owner_id` = ? ;
```

The tables have all appropriate indices. I can't denormalize the table by adding a `breed` column to the `animals` table because it is possible for animals to be assigned multiple breeds. I also have this problem with a few other large tables that have one-to-many relationships.

Is there a more performant way to achieve what I'm looking for? It seems like a pretty simple problem but I can't seem to figure out the best way to achieve this other than pre-calculating and caching the results.

Here is the explain output from my query. Notice the `Using temporary`

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   "SIMPLE"    "a" NULL    "ref"   "PRIMARY,animals_animal_id_index"   "animals_animal_id_index"   "153"   "const" 1126303 100.00  "Using index; Using temporary"
1   "SIMPLE"    "ab"    NULL    "ref"   "animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,animal_breeds_animal_id_index,animal_breeds_breed_index"  "animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique"  "5" "pedigreeonline.a.id"   1   100.00  "Using index"
```

And as requested, here are the create table statements (I left off a few unrelated columns and indices from the `animals` table). I believe the `animal_breeds_animal_id_index` index on `animal_breeds` table is redundant because of the unique key on the table, but we can ignore that for now as long as it's not causing the problem :)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `animals` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `animals_animal_id_index` (`owner_id`,`id`),
  KEY `animals_name_index` (`name`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2470843 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE `animal_breeds` (
  `animal_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `breed` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique` (`animal_id`,`breed`),
  KEY `animal_breeds_animal_id_index` (`animal_id`),
  KEY `animal_breeds_breed_index` (`breed`),
  CONSTRAINT `animal_breeds_animal_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`animal_id`) REFERENCES `animals` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: CREATE TABLE statements would be nice

Comment: Updated with CREATE TABLE statements

Comment: Drop the KEY `animal_breeds_animal_id_index` (`animal_id`),

Comment: Yeah I realize it's redundant. I've already dropped the key since editing my answer, but it didn't help the query speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With knowledge about your data you can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT `breed`
        FROM
            `animal_breeds`
    ) AS b
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            animal_breeds AS ab
            INNER JOIN animals AS a ON ab.animal_id = a.id
        WHERE
            b.breed = ab.breed
            AND a.owner_id = ?
    )
;
```

The idea is to get short list of distinct breeds without any filtering (for small list it would be quite fast) and then filter further the list with correlated subquery. As the list is short it would be only few subqueries executed and they will only check for existence that is much faster that any grouping (distinct == grouping).

This will only work if your distinct list is quite short.

With random generated data based on your answers the above query gave me the following execution plan:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ALL                 2   100.00  
3   SUBQUERY    a       ref PRIMARY,animals_animal_id_index animals_animal_id_index 153 const   1011    100.00  Using index
3   SUBQUERY    ab      ref animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,`animal_breeds_animal_id_index`,animal_breeds_animal_id_index  `animal_breeds_animal_id_index` 5   test.a.id   2   100.00  Using index
2   DERIVED animal_breeds       range   animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,`animal_breeds_breed_index`,animal_breeds_breed_index  `animal_breeds_breed_index` 1022        2   100.00  Using index for group-by
```

Alternatively, you can try to create WHERE clause like this:

```
...
WHERE
    b.breed IN (
        SELECT
            ab.breed
        FROM
            animal_breeds AS ab
            INNER JOIN animals AS a ON ab.animal_id = a.id
        WHERE
            a.owner_id = ?
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm away from my computer the next few days but I think might be a perfect solution. I'll check it out soon and mark this as solved if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ab.`breed`
FROM `animal_breeds` ab INNER JOIN
     `animals` a
      ON a.`id` = ab.`animal_id` 
WHERE a.`owner_id` = ? ;
```

You want indexes on `animals(owner_id, id)` and `animal_breeds(animal_id, breed)`.  The order of the columns in the composite index is important.

With the right index, I imagine that this will be very fast.

EDIT:

According to the explain, there are 1,126,303 matches for the values you are using.  The time is due to removing duplicates.  Given the sizes of the tables, it is surprising that there would be so many matching one value.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I do have those two composite keys in the exact order. I've updated my question with the output of my `EXPLAIN`. It's not named the best but the 'animals_animal_id_index` is in fact (animal,id).

Comment: Are you sure about your indexes? I do not see any index with owner mentioned on "a" in explain. It would be nice if you provide show create table outputs. Gordon mentioned index (owner_id, id), not (animal_id, id) and this is hudge difference.

Comment: @fifonik Sorry for the confusion, but yes I am sure. I changed one column name in my question/comments (from "animal" to "owner_id") to make it slightly less confusing in my OP, but clearly it just added more confusion

Comment: Regarding your edit: yes, there are a lot of duplicate breed values in the `animal_breeds` table. There are about 2.5M records but only ~250 unique breeds. If I run the query without the join on the `animals` table the query only takes about 300ms, so I don't think the time is from removing duplicates? Or does the duplicate removal technique change when using a join vs non-join? I'm also not quite sure what you mean by "it is surprising that there would be so many matching one value." Can you please explain?

Comment: @Jeff . . . This isn't about how many breeds are in the table.  Your plan is suggesting that one owner matches over a million rows in `animal_breeds`.  That seems like a lot, given the size of the tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No it is completely correct, I'm not sure how you're inferring that opinion other than the term "owner." Ignore that column name, it's arbitrary. The "animals" and "animals_breed" tables will have millions of records and the "animals.owner_id" column will have only a few unique values. I don't think that should make any difference to the execution of this query?